# How to establishing a PHP connection with SOAP API with WSSE

Tags: php, soap

I need help! I've search almost everywhere, but unfortunately there is not much information about PHP & SOAP & WSSE. Im posting here and see if anyone can help me out.
I'm using this library to connect to a SOAP Service using WSSE: http://goo.gl/en7hvh
And this is my connection settings: http://pastebin.com/vc3X5aDj but i'm getting this error:

```
 Fault string: Unauthorized request. Make sure the Customer name, User and 
 Password are provided.

 Fault code: soap:Client
```

I already double checked my username & password, they both are correct. And if i call the getLastResponse and getLastReponseRequest, this comes up:

```
 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 20 Mar 2014 23:43:53 GMT Content-Length: 1226

 http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/faulturn:uuid:b38a9ad8-d819-463c-a801-122009040f04urn:uuid:3f9247a3-4cbd-4d0d-964a-bf9182867d4ahttp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous2014-03-20T23:43:53Z2014-03-20T23:48:53Zsoap:ClientUnauthorized request. Make sure the Customer name, User and Password are provided.
```

This is the request I need to generate: http://pastebin.com/aRMmVMj0
I dont know what am I missing.... Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your pain, luckily I have overcomed it!

```
class WSSEAuth {

   private $Username;
   private $Password;

   function __construct($username, $password) {
      $this->Username = $username;
      $this->Password = $password;
   }

}

class WSSEToken {

   private $UsernameToken;

   function __construct($innerVal) {
      $this->UsernameToken = $innerVal;
   }

}

class MySoapClient {

   private $username;
   private $password;
   private $options;
   private $header;
   private $wsdl;
   private $wsse;
   private $gw;
   public $start_time;

   public function getClient($wsse, $user, $pw, $wsdl, $gw) {

      $this->wsse = $wsse;
      $this->username = $user;
      $this->password = $pw;
      $this->wsdl = $wsdl;
      $this->gw = $gw;
      $this->start_time = microtime(true);

      $this->options = array(
          'trace'=>1,
          'username'=>$this->username,
          'password'=>$this->password,
          'exceptions'=>true,
          'connection_timeout'=>5,
      );

      $objSoapVarUser = new SoapVar($this->username, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wsse, NULL, $this->wsse);
      $objSoapVarPass = new SoapVar($this->password, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wsse, NULL, $this->wsse);
      $objWSSEAuth = new WSSEAuth($objSoapVarUser, $objSoapVarPass);
      $objSoapVarWSSEAuth = new SoapVar($objWSSEAuth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wsse, 'UsernameToken', $this->wsse);
      $objWSSEToken = new WSSEToken($objSoapVarWSSEAuth);
      $objSoapVarWSSEToken = new SoapVar($objWSSEToken, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wsse, 'UsernameToken', $this->wsse);
      $this->header = new SoapVar($objSoapVarWSSEToken, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wsse, 'Security', $this->wsse);
      $objSoapVarWSSEHeader[] = new SoapHeader($this->wsse, 'Security', $this->header, true, $this->gw);

      $objClient = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, $this->options);
      $objClient->__setSoapHeaders($objSoapVarWSSEHeader);

      return $objClient;
   }

}
```

After all those Classes, do this:

```
$var = new MySoapClient;
$var_client = $var->getClient('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'your_user', 'your_password', 'your_wsdl', 'your_gate');
```

And then for example, you could invoke something like:

```
$var_client->__soapCall('Function', $soap_payload);
```

Edit: I fixed some typos!

Comment: I'm sorry but im totally new to SOAP, your code looks really understandable but I still don't know what goes in the 'your_gate' parameter, and the $soap_payload variable. Care to explain a little further with these 2 values?

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. for the $soap_payload I added this array('parameters'=>$params) and for the gate I used FALSE. And it works, but the code I had works too. It just that the IT Department in charge of this API forgot to activate my username... I spent the whole week trying to set this up... Thanks for your code, im using this, since it's more readable than the one I had!

Comment: Some .wsdl's have gates setup at the same place, without the .wsdl.
It's just a waypoint.

The payload is an array, however, you can transform the Soap PHP Object which I prefer because it allows complex namspaces, that array's can't, and some .wsdl's are just way too complex for a simple array.  Cheers